# How to download dataset of Kaggle to Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

I'm trying to download the dataset from this Kaggle competition:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/pku-autonomous-driving/overview

into Google Colab.

I've downloaded my .json file from Kaggle and used the following commands:

```
# Upload data to Google Colab
import os
os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = "xxxxxx" # username from the json file
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" # key from the json file
!kaggle competitions download -c pku-autonomous-driving # api copied from kaggle
```

But this downloads all the files into Google Collab without making any folders in the process and saves everything alltogether, eventually after a few minutes it fails because there're too many requests to download.

**My question is:** How can I download it as a `.zip` file, or any other way to download it into Google Collab? (I did search before asking here, but didn't find a great solution)?

I also tried clicking the download button near the Competition API, and copied the link, and tried with `!wget ("link address")` but this also fails and doesn't start to download the files.

I have other options I can try like uploading it into my Google Drive and then mounting it, but I do want to know if there's a way around it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file from Kaggle to Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673074/download-file-from-kaggle-to-google-colab)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify where to download to by using the `-p` (or `--path`) flag:

`!kaggle competitions download pku-autonomous-driving -p data_folder/`