# Connection error with '!pip install torchxrayvision' on kaggle

Tags: python, pip, kaggle

When I run the following code in my kaggle notebook, i get an error.

```
import os,sys
sys.path.insert(0,"..")
sys.path.insert(0,"../..")
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision
import sys
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pandas as pd
```

This part works fine.

`!pip install torchxrayvision`

This produces an error. The error message is:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3e22307cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/torchxrayvision/

Strangely, in another, older kaggle notebook I can run the same code without an error.
What ist the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: How are you running `sys.path.insert(0,"..")` before importing `sys`?

Comment: The first half of the text of your question seems irrelevant. The posted code does not seem to be related to the error message. -- You seem to simply have connection issues or encryption issues. Are you using an old Python or an old _pip_?

Comment: I found the error: In the settings of the kaggle notebook, "Internet" was turned off.

Comment: You need to answer your own question next time, a comment is not enough. Else, someone else can just do it for you, as was done here.

Answer (score 2):

[Just turn the on switch for internet access in your notebook settings and try again;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE9Hd.png)

Comment: In my settings, it says: "Want more power? Access free GPU or turn on an internet connection. Get phone verified". Thus, you must register with your phone number before you can do this. And that reveals a lot of yourself: in which country you have your phone contract, and your social media accounts if they are linked with your phone number, and you could even be tracked with this. Not saying that you should not do it, it is just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to download the notebook from Kaggle and open the notebook in Google Colab. Then you do not have to switch on the internet conection in the settings only to get the power of `! pip` or `! apt`.

If you need to load a Kaggle dataset into your Colab notebook:

- For downloading a whole dataset, see [Download dataset from Kaggle to Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673074/download-file-from-kaggle-to-google-colab).
- For downloading a chosen file of a whole dataset, see [How to load just one chosen file of a way too large Kaggle dataset from Kaggle into Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67713193/how-to-load-just-one-chosen-file-of-a-way-too-large-kaggle-dataset-from-kaggle-i).

Answer (score 0):

Click the **NOTEBOOK OPTIONS** in you right hand side, find the Internet setting and trun it on.